# Is it safe to use an "18v ~ 20v" power brick/adapter for a device that originally had an 18v adapter?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, charger, adapter

We have a device that uses an [18v adapter/power brick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS51W.jpg), unfortunately the adapter broke. As a replacement, we are considering an [adapter that has a "18v ~ 20v" rating printed on its back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSAeU.jpg). There is no switch whatsoever on the power brick to adjust the output voltage. The person selling the item says that the voltage will basically adjust itself based on the device being powered.

Question: **Can I use a power brick labeled "18v ~ 20v" for a device that originally had an 18v adapter? Or will this be harmful to my device**? Could the self adjusting voltage statement be true?

I understand that for voltages, it is necessary to look for an exact match, while for the amps, we just need to match the minimum. It's just that it's the first time I saw a "~" in the voltage indicator of a power brick. I'm really hoping to be able to use this, since other available options are 19v.

**EDIT:**

About the device being powered:
This is the machine meant to be powered by the adapter: https://cricut.com/en_us/machines/cricut-explore-air-2.html

A video of it in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdkyoMDQ5Pw

As can be deduced, it has several stepper motors and several circuit boards.

[Image of what the main board with the DC input looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUIe5.jpg)

[Another image of the main board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkjBv.jpg)

[A photo of one of the motors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYasX.jpg)

A troubleshooting video showing the DC board among other parts: https://youtu.be/aNqq-6n_vqs?t=836

A teardown video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ergcvPaaVwk

Comment: It depends on the device, what is it?

Comment: *The person selling the item says that the voltage will basically adjust itself based on the device being powered* That is a dubious statement in my opinion. In my opinion, whoever said this **has no clue**. If the 18 ~20 V adapter is OK for your device depends on the device, realize that **trying** while the device cannot handle this voltage, can **damage** the device. I would simply get an 18 V, 2.5 A (or more than 2.5 A) adapter, pay attention to the polarity and use that. I would **not** use the 18 ~20 V adapter, to me it looks like a **very cheap, poor quality** adapter.

Comment: @JaySabir The device is a desktop cutting machine (like a printer, but cuts instead of prints). Here's a link: https://cricut.com/en_us/machines/cricut-explore-air-2.html

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I would have preferred an 18V brick as well, but to be honest, that's the best looking one I found.  the others are basically iterations of this adapter from aliexpress costing less than 10 USD https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32992033664.html

Comment: The real reason why the rating is 18 V ~20 V is probably due to the **poor quality** of the adapter. Inside a good quality adapter there will be a **voltage feedback** that will keep the voltage constant, whatever the load current is (within limits of course). In this poor quality adapter, the voltage regulation might be done in a cheaper way (like feedback through transfomer) which results in the output voltage dropping as the load current increases.

Comment: So I guess the 18V~20V is basically a bug, not a feature. That makes more sense.  And yes, I think the seller may have said that "auto-adjust" statement out of lack of knowledge.

Comment: Actually it is a "feature" due to the cheap design. That desktop cutting machine to me looks too expensive to be using it with an adapter that is possibly outputting a too high voltage. If the design of the cutting machine is good it can handle it but as we don't know what that design looks like, it will be a gamble. Note that if you damage the machine by using the wrong adapter, you might break it and the manufacturer will not give you warranty.

Comment: We've contacted the local vendor of the machine, but we haven't received a proper response yet.  We'd prefer a replacement from the manufacturer, but given the time constraints, then there's a possibility of just taking chances with the aliexpress option if this 18v ~ 20v option seems infeasiible.

Comment: I expect it is 20V up to 2A then 18V @ 4A, and is more likely OK for loads with DCDC converters in them.  That's why 19.5V appears to be the new std.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The  "18v~20v" adapter does not really have a switch or toggle to choose between 18v, 19v, or 20v though. Does this mean that the voltage adjusts itself automatically depending on the device to be powered? I am not sure what a DCDC is supposed to look like, but  I have updated the post to contain images and videos of some of the internal  boards and motors of the device to be powered.

Comment: It means poor quality and regulation so like a battery drops voltage with rising current.

Answer (score 1):

The power supply cannot adjust itself automatically to what the device expects. It can adjust the output voltage to try to compensate for the voltage drop on the wires based on current draw though, but the original is only rated 2.5A and the replacement is rated up to 4A. Get a proper 18V replacement, with 2.5A or more current rating.

Comment: I agree on getting a better suitable adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately, current options are limited to that one I posted or aliexpress "universal adapters" https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32992033664.html which look much flimsier.  I would probably have a replacement shipped from the manufacturer, but that would take too long.

Comment: `It can adjust the output voltage to try to compensate for the voltage drop on the wires based on current draw though` i'm trying to parse what this means. Does this mean that voltage can increase based on the amount of electricity the device is using?

Comment: It is possible. But you don't have a datasheet that tells you how it works. Don't buy anything unless you know how it works. If the old adapter has a 3 prong grounded mains input and the output is also grounded, do not buy an ungrounded power supply. You risk damaging something if the device has any external connections to computers or other devices.

Comment: Apart from checking a data sheet, is there any other way to check output voltage? Would it be best to just purchase a multimeter to test, if that's what's necessary? Or would it still be unsafe? I'm sure they can let me test the adapter while plugged before purchasing.

Comment: You can measure voltage. But there is no saying what the voltage is with no load and when compared to with an attached load. You don't even mention what is the rating of the load.

Comment: I've checked the literature that came with the machine as well as the stickers on the machine, but the usual electrical details on devices could not be found.  The best I found was this youtube troubleshooting video showing the main board of the machine where the dc input is attached https://youtu.be/aNqq-6n_vqs?t=836 and a tear down video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ergcvPaaVwk . I don't know if it's even possible to sleuth out the total attached load from the board. Thanks for the responses so far.